# Ansible - getting an item from one list based on a value from another

Tags: list, ansible, jinja2

I have a list of site information like this:

```
sites:
  - {host: host1, path: path1, db: db1 }
  - {host: host2, path: path2, db: db2 }
  - {host: host3, path: path3, db: db3 }
```

And database info in lists like this:

```
mysql_databases:
 - { name: db1, encoding: utf8mb4, collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci }
 - { name: db2, encoding: utf8mb4, collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci }
 - { name: db3, encoding: utf8mb4, collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci }

mysql_users:
  - { name: db1, host: "%", password: pass1, priv: "db1.*:ALL", db: db1 }
  - { name: db2, host: "%", password: pass2, priv: "db2.*:ALL", db: db2 }
  - { name: db3, host: "%", password: pass3, priv: "db3.*:ALL", db: db3 }
```

I have a role that creates a credentials file using the above information. Something like this:

```
- name: Create file
  template:
    src: "credentials.conf.j2"
    dest: "{{ item.path}}/{{ item.name }}.conf"
  with_items: "{{ sites }}"
```

Is there any way to send the template the corresponding info from all three lists while tranversing the `sites` list?

The lists have been structured like this for ease of use with geerlingguy's mysql role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A systemic approach would be to convert the mysql_* lists to dictionaries. For example

```
- set_fact:
    db_dict: "{{ db_dict|default({})|combine({item.name: item}) }}"
  loop: "{{ mysql_databases }}"
- set_fact:
    users_dict: "{{ users_dict|default({})|combine({item.name: item}) }}"
  loop: "{{ mysql_users }}"
- template:
    src: credentials.conf.j2
    dest: "{{ item.path}}/{{ item.db }}.conf"
  loop: "{{ sites }}"
```

Then, manipulation with properly structured data is trivial. For example the template

```
$ cat credentials.conf.j2
{% for k,v in db_dict[item.db].iteritems() %}
{{ k }}: {{ v }}
{% endfor %}

{% for k,v in users_dict[item.db].iteritems() %}
{{ k }}: {{ v }}
{% endfor %}
```

gives

```
$ cat path1/db1.conf 
collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
name: db1
encoding: utf8mb4

host: %
password: pass1
db: db1
name: db1
priv: db1.*:ALL
```

It's possible to remove the attribute `name` from the dictionaries. For example

```
- set_fact:
    db_dict: "{{ db_dict|default({})|
                 combine({item.name: item|dict2items|
                                     rejectattr('key', 'match', 'name')|
                                     list|items2dict}) }}"
  loop: "{{ mysql_databases }}"
- debug:
    var: db_dict

- set_fact:
    users_dict: "{{ users_dict|default({})|
                 combine({item.name: item|dict2items|
                                     rejectattr('key', 'match', 'name')|
                                     list|items2dict}) }}"
  loop: "{{ mysql_users }}"
- debug:
    var: users_dict
```

gives

```
"db_dict": {
    "db1": {
        "collation": "utf8mb4_unicode_ci", 
        "encoding": "utf8mb4"
    }, 
    "db2": {
        "collation": "utf8mb4_unicode_ci", 
        "encoding": "utf8mb4"
    }, 
    "db3": {
        "collation": "utf8mb4_unicode_ci", 
        "encoding": "utf8mb4"
    }
}
```

and

```
"users_dict": {
    "db1": {
        "db": "db1", 
        "host": "%", 
        "password": "pass1", 
        "priv": "db1.*:ALL"
    }, 
    "db2": {
        "db": "db2", 
        "host": "%", 
        "password": "pass2", 
        "priv": "db2.*:ALL"
    }, 
    "db3": {
        "db": "db3", 
        "host": "%", 
        "password": "pass3", 
        "priv": "db3.*:ALL"
    }
}
```

Then,

```
- template:
    src: credentials.conf.j2
    dest: "{{ item.path}}/{{ item.db }}.conf"
  loop: "{{ sites }}"
```

gives

```
$ cat path1/db1.conf 
collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
encoding: utf8mb4

host: %
password: pass1
db: db1
priv: db1.*:ALL
```

Comment: Awesome, clear answer! I didn't know about dictionaries or how to create them from lists. Thanks!